# Save signature in PDF document in Android Ionic 3 Application

Tags: android, ionic3, adobe, electronic-signature, signaturepad

Is there any API or SDK available to do Sign and save in pdf document provided by Adobe ([Sign and Save](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/capture-and-sync-your-signature.html)) or any other providers (happy if it is open source ). I need to incorporate in my Application. It is an Android Native application or Ionic 3 Application.

I have tried signature pad ( [signaturepad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signature-pad) ) but have no idea to embed or drag and drop on top of existing pdf file downloaded in the device and save the same. Looking for the possibilities and options.

Comment: You can use the Ionic Native File Transfer plugin to achieve this. https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/. I'm not 100% sure if you'll be able to convert an svg file which is your signature to pdf, but I do know you can convert to png. Maybe these resources will help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274786/file-upload-using-ionic-native  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080538/send-signature-from-signature-pad-ionic-3/53859968#53859968

Comment: Just found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-pdf-generator

Comment: But my requirement is, i need to open an existing pdf file and the page which open the page should have the option to generate signature and the user can drag and save the signature to the pdf. I created Signature Application separately but have no idea to place the signature on top of existing pdf and save the same as pdf. Thanks.